# AngularJS Data sharing between two controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a issue in sharing data between 2 controllers and 2 views. I have 2 views. I created 2 separate controllers and bind with 2 different views. Now I have 2 share data between 2 controllers so I created a service. Issues is one controller get data from remote source and other controller is consuming that data. But the view that consumes data loads first, so pulled data from remote source is not exactly utilize by first one. Eg.

```
//My Services
as.service('songGenreService', function () {
    var genreList = [];

    var addGenres = function (newObj) {
        genreList = newObj;
    };

    var getGenres = function () {
        return genreList;
    };

    return {
        addGenres: addGenres,
        getGenres: getGenres
    };
});


as.controller('SongListController', ['$scope', 'Song', "$stateParams", 'Category', 'Album', 'base64', 'langConversion', 'CONFIG', 'Poet', "songGenreService",
    function ($scope, Song, $stateParams, Category, Album, base64, langConversion, CONFIG, Poet, songGenreService) {          

        $scope.getCategories = function () {
            Category.find({
                filter: {
                    fields: ["id", "name"],
                    where: {
                        parentId: 2
                    }
                }
            }).$promise.then(function (categories) {

                $scope.categories = categories;// Here I am giving data to other source.
                songGenreService.addGenres(categories);

                $scope.genreId = $scope.categories[0].id;
                $scope.genreName = $scope.categories[0].name;
            });
        }();
}
]);

as.controller('SongGenreController', ['$scope', 'Song', "songGenreService",
    function ($scope, Song, songGenreService) {
        $scope.categories = songGenreService.getGenres();
        console.log($scope.categories);
    }
]);
```

Issue is "SongGenreController" loads first because of HTML as it loads first. I wish to populate it when data loads successfully. "songGenreService.getGenres();" doesn't run with remote source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed a similar issue is by using a publish subscribe mechanism.
In your service you can put a publish when genres are added like so:

```
var addGenres = function (newObj) {
         genreList = newObj;
         $rootScope.$broadcast('genresUpdated, genreList);
    };
```

then in your two controllers you subscribe to the event :

```
$scope.$on('genresUpdated', function(event, genreList){
     $scope.genres = genreList;
     // and other code you want to have triggered when the genreList changes
});
```

Comment: `$scope.$on` I have to add this to the second controller where its pulling data from first one. Right? Or in both controllers?

Comment: I would add this to both controllers.

Comment: You can look at it like this. Your service is the parent and he holds all the data. Your controllers are the children and they want the data so the controller gives them a copy that they can store in their local scope. But when they add something by calling the parent add method, they also want their local copy to stay up to date. so they subscribe on changes in the parent. the service in turn does a publish to notify the children when data has changed